# Representability in a formal theory

Tags: logic

A wff $\phi(v_{1}, \dots , v_{k})$ $represents$ a relation $R \subseteq N^k$ in theory $T$ iff for every $(n_{1},\dots,n_{k}) \in N^K$:

$$
 (n_{1},\dots,n_{k}) \in R \implies T \vdash \phi(\mathbf{n_{1}}, \dots , \mathbf{n_{k}})
$$
$$
 (n_{1},\dots,n_{k}) \notin R \implies T \vdash \lnot \phi(\mathbf{n_{1}}, \dots , \mathbf{n_{k}})
$$

If T is a consistent theory, does every wff represent a relation in T?

Comment: I have deleted my earlier answer, since it didn't actually address the question you asked.  But consider any undecidable sentence $\phi$, and add a dummy variable $x$.  Since $\phi$ is a sentence, the relation $R$ is either $N$ or $\emptyset$, depending on whether $N\models\phi$.  But since $\phi$ is undecidable, you do not have $T\vdash \phi$ or $T\vdash \neg\phi$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three ways that your proposition can fail.

The first involves nonstandard elements.  If there are elements of $\vert\mathfrak{A}\vert $ which don't have names, then the right hand side of the "representability" equation isn't even defined. For example, suppose that $\mathbb {N} $ is a nonstandard model of the theory $ T $ of arithmetic and that $ n $ is a nonstandard integer.  Then the language can't say anything specific about $ n $ since it had no name for it.

I guess you could ask whether $\phi (x) $ can represent a formula in *any* model, but even if we assume that all elements of the models have names, that doesn't solve the problem.

Let $ T $ be the theory of arithmetic and let $\mathbb {N} $ be the standard model. Let $\phi (n) $ be the formula encoding "$ n $ is the Godel number of a provable formula." Then the incompleteness theorem tells us that the induced relation is not representable.

But even much weaker theories have the same problem.  Suppose $ T =\emptyset $ and $ \phi (x) $ is any atomic formula. Then regardless of the model, or the element $ n $, we do not have $ T\vdash \phi (n) $ or $ T\vdash\neg \phi( n) $.